# Break into debugger on OpenGL errors on Android

Tags: android, debugging, opengl-es, android-ndk

Is it possible to set Android debugger (gdb) to break into the debugger on every OpenGL error resulting from GL function calls (also native code), same as it is [possible in Xcode with iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/AddinganOpenGLESErrorBreakpoint/AddinganOpenGLESErrorBreakpoint.html)?

(Basically, looking for a way to avoid wrapping all of your GL calls in glGetError checks when looking for a bug.)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `GLSurfaceView`, you can call the following method on your `GLSurfaceView` instance:

```
setDebugFlags(GLSurfaceView.DEBUG_CHECK_GL_ERROR);
```

After this, `glGetError()` will be called after each GL call, and an exception will be fired if it returns an error.

You should typically call this before calling `setRenderer()`.

Comment: Thanks. This is done in the GLSurfaceView Java class? Should've specified I'm working on native code.